# Почему не сменяется фон?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Всем привет! Сначала были проблемы с фоном, но после множества попыток, я смог зафиксировать фон, чтобы он не сменялся после обновления или перехода с помощью localStorage, теперь же я не понимаю, почему по истечении времени ( пример 3сек) он не меняется.

Прошу подсказать, как исправить это? Думаю недописанно именно в localStorage, но не знаю как её подправить. Спасибо всем!

```js
 window.onload = function() {
            const date = new Date();
            const time = date.getHours() + ':' +addZero(date.getMinutes());
            document.getElementsByTagName('div') [1].innerHTML = time;
            window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
            function addZero(num) {
                var str = num.toString();
                return str.length == 1? "0" + str : str;
            };
        } ();
        
        
 function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
            return  Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min))
        }
            let randomItem = getRandomArbitrary(0,36)
                if(window.innerWidth = 1600) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('p1')[randomItem].style.display="block";
}


localStorage.setItem('name', 'conteiner');
document.getElementById('conteiner').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('name');
localStorage.removeItem('name');

const phr = new Array();
phr.push("https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/les_tuman_derevia_126479_1920x1080.jpg");
phr.push("https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/gory_ozero_vershiny_vid_sverkhu_119133_1920x1080.jpg");

function Rotator_cont() {
  const s = 3000;
  const N = phr.length;
  const i = Math.round(Math.random() * (N));
  Rotator(i);

  function Rotator(i) {
    i++;
    if (i > N - 1) {
      i = 0
    }; //alert(i);
    document.getElementById('conteiner').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + phr[i] + ')';
    timerId01 = setTimeout(function() {
      Rotator(i)
    }, s);
    return;
  }
}
Rotator_cont()
```

```css
#conteiner {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
 }
 
 .mainTime {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 110px;
    font-size: 200px;
    color:white;
    
}
.mainWord {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 190px;
    color:white;
}

.p1 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteiner">
  <div class="mainTime"></div>
  <div class="mainWord">
    <div class="p1">Fortune favors the brave</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Хорошо, люди указали на ошибку с #. 
Но теперь, в окне "conteiner", локал не работает, ошибка в консоли та же(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined), и фон сменяется по таймеру.

Поясню что я пытаюсь сделать: Вот есть Я(пользователь) я на странице , вижу фон (у него 5 мин таймер). Закрыл страницу. Через 3 мин. я захожу снова и вижу тот же фон. Снова закрыл. Но через 10 минут я зайду и фон уже сменился. Т.е. сохранить в local сам таймер + фон который был у пользователя.

Сам фон привязан к пустому div, думаю в этом и есть проблема ошибки.

Comment: Все неправильно. Научитесь сначала делать простые вещи: проверять условия (`if(window.innerWidth = 1600) {`) и назначать обработчики (`window.onload = function() {...} ();`). Зачем Вы включили в вопрос пример, который содержит ошибки, заведомо не имеющие отношения к задаче, которую Вы пытаетесь решить (`getRandomArbitrary(0,36)`)?

Comment: Как Вы думаете, что делает эта строчка `localStorage.setItem('name', 'conteiner');`?

Comment: @Igor, я знаю, я знаю! :-)

Comment: @Grundy "Кто знает - тот молчит!"

Comment: @igor к 2 комменту, ключ значение. Если вызовом getItem ввести ключ, то нужно получить значение из хранилища. Задал вопрос именно поэтому, что не могу внести и запомнить значение , а после получить его.

Comment: @Igor, ...тот ест!

Comment: @AntonBrock, _Задал вопрос именно поэтому, что не могу внести и запомнить значение , а после получить его_ - собственно в `set` ты его вносишь, следующей строчкой `get` читаешь, и потом сразу же удаляешь.

Comment: @AntonBrock Кхм, кхм... Это что, ответ на вопрос "что делает эта строчка"?

Comment: @Grundy, хорошо, тогда нужно задать время перед удаление ( внести значение таймера и фона(который есть), а как добавить таймер на local и вообще возможно ли это?

Comment: @AntonBrock Попробуйте критически посмотреть на Ваш вопрос. Вы до сих пор не объяснили, какого поведения Вы пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: @Igor разве ? Вроде объяснил. 
" Вот есть Я(пользователь) я на странице , вижу фон (у него 5 мин таймер). Закрыл страницу. Через 3 мин. я захожу снова и вижу тот же фон. Снова закрыл. Но через 10 минут я зайду и фон уже сменился. Т.е. сохранить в local сам таймер + фон который был у пользователя."

Comment: @AntonBrock Вы не можете сохранить в `localStorage` "таймер". Вы можете сохранить в `localStorage` строковое представление времени.

Comment: @Igor тогда как мне зафиксировать прошедшего кол.времени ? Преобразовывать его , а после парсить? Именно этого я не понимаю. Я знаю на сколько кривой код. Я не понимаю, сам подход сохранить значение времени и фона, а после изменения его или не сбрасывания его, даже при закрытие.

Comment: Подход к реализации таймера плохой. Вам нужно сохранять в localStorage только время последнего изменения фона (в виде строки ISO  например) и при загрузке страницы сравнивать текущее время и сохранённое. Если разница больше чем Х времени изменить фон, если нет, оставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема находится в строке:

```
document.getElementById('#conteiner').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('name');
```

Элемента с id `#conteiner` нет, поэтому при выполнении данной строки появлялась ошибка и далее выполнение кода просто не шло.

Для исправления можно просто убрать эту строку, либо убрать из селектора `#`, чтобы осталось просто `.getElementById('conteiner')`, как это уже есть в коде ниже:

```
document.getElementById('conteiner').style.backgroundImage
```

Comment: Так и сделал , понял что идет тавтология, но теперь фон сменяется, локал не работает, в окне надпись "conteiner"  и та же ошибка в консоли

Comment: @AntonBrock, та же ошибка - это какая?:)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: @AntonBrock _в окне надпись "conteiner"_ - если надпись появилась, значит ошибки уже нет. Возможно это просто старый вывод.

Comment: и кеш обновил, и снова сохранил и открыл , ошибка также присутствует

Comment: @AntonBrock, в твоем codepen, я вижу ошибку чтения style у undefined, и она происходит потому, что  ты рассчитываешь на наличие 37 элементов с классом `p1`, а у тебя есть только один такой элемент. Ошибка с innerHTML происходит потому что `document.getElementsByTagName` не ищет вложенные дивы, и  так как у тебя он только один - эта ошибка появляется

Comment: я тут их стер , чтобы не было слишком большого кол.элементов. А так их много, да.

Comment: @AntonBrock, вообще в коде все печально: `.innerHTML` стирает полностью все содержимое элемента, поэтому когда ты заменил содержимое `conteiner` на строку, все остальные скрипты, которые обращались к внутренним элементам начинают падать.

Comment: хорошо , как тогда мне сделать так, чтобы ничего не подало ? Понятно, что переписать, но я не понимаю , как именно нужно сохранить значение фона и времени (таймера)

Comment: @AntonBrock, как минимум не используй `.innerHTML`. собственно совсем непонятно, зачем ты меняешь html у самого контейнера.

Comment: @Grundy Потому что он думает, что `innerHTML` содержит стили элемента.

Comment: @Grundy ... а `localStorage.setItem('name', 'conteiner');` сохраняет в `localStorage` `innerHTML` элемента с `id="conteiner"`.